# Setting the system date in Python (on Windows)

Tags: python, datetime, date

There appears to be many packages for getting/formatting the current date, or finding out the date n time intervals from now. But I must be overlooking the existence of a simple method to set the date (like Windows' date.exe) in Python.

Surely such a function exists? I've been unable to find anything on Google, the python docs (datetime, time, os, etc) or stack overflow. TIA.

edit: To summarize,[this](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/06/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-in/) page tells you how to **get** them.

And you can set them using either

```
win32api.SetSystemTime(year,month,dayOfWeek,day,hour,minute,second,millseconds)
```

or

```
os.system("date " + mm/dd/yy)
```

date.exe also appears to accept mm-dd-yy, 4-digit years, and probably other alternatives.

I prefer the latter for simplicity.

Comment: From MSDN: `The wDayOfWeek member of the SYSTEMTIME structure is ignored.` The date command is fickle and will break depending on regional settings so it's best to avoid it if you want your code to work on multiple environments.

Comment: `SetSystemTime` expects the parameters in UTC time. The page OP linked to mentions `datetime.datetime.now()` but one will need to use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` if passing the results into `win32api.SetSystemTime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [win32api.SetSystemTime](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__SetSystemTime_meth.html).  This is part of [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/).

Comment: Strange that python doesn't have something like this by default.

Comment: Why would they make that function require a day of week parameter?  And it really would be great if you could just pass a Python datetime object.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not use os.system("shell_cmd_in_here") to call the linux cmd:

```
date -s "2 OCT 2010 18:00:00"
```

This would set the system date to: 2 Oct 2010 18:00:00 for example.

So altogether it is:

```
os.system('date -s "2 OCT 2010 18:00:00"')
```

Comment: A sudo, on windows?  Also, what guarantee do you have that 'date' even checks stdin?

Comment: Sorry thought you were on linux. You can do the same for Windows, see this link on how to set the date via command prompt http://ss64.com/nt/date.html. Just put the 'set date' cmd within your os.system() call.

Answer (score 0):

on Windows you can use basically os for this

get date:

```
os.system("date")
```

get time:

```
os.system("time")
```

set date:

```
os.system("date "+str(mm-dd-yyyy))
```

set time:

```
os.system("time "+str(hh:mm:ss.ms))
```

You should run the script as administrator with whatever you use cmd, vscode etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import pywin32
import pywintypes

# Set the new time (year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
new_time = datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 8, 15, 30, 0)

# Get the system time settings
system_time = pywintypes.SYSTEMTIME(
    year=new_time.year,
    month=new_time.month,
    day_of_week=new_time.weekday(),
    day=new_time.day,
    hour=new_time.hour,
    minute=new_time.minute,
    second=new_time.second,
    millisecond=0
)

# Set the system time (requires administrative privileges)
pywin32.SetSystemTime(system_time)

print("System time changed successfully.")
```