# What is the recommended method to convert a datetime object to millisecond unix timestamp?

Tags: python

If I have a datetime object like

```
datetime.datetime(2016,4,5,10,4,7,000)
```

How would I convert it to unix timestamp with millisecond accuracy?

I am using python version 2.7.10. The solution here ([How can I convert a datetime object to milliseconds since epoch (unix time) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p))  using total_seconds seems to round to the nearest second on my system.

Comment: It doesn't "round", it uses a function whose resolution is whole seconds. You can extract the `microseconds` field from the `timedelta` object and add it as an additional step.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `timestamp()` method.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2016,4,5,10,4,7,000).timestamp()
1459875847.0
>>> datetime.datetime(2016,4,5,10,4,7,123456).timestamp()
1459875847.123456
```

Comment: this is not available in python < 3.3.

Comment: And is that what you're using? You never specified.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind an inefficient solution then you can change system date and time, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081310/python-module-to-change-system-date-and-time) for reference and then get the time stamp using `time.time()`.

Better methods must exist, its just a work around.