# How can one allow python app to change system time

Tags: python, linux

I am working on a project that has python software running and handling data from multiple devices and sensors on a single board computer. Since one of the devices is an INS (Inertial Navigation System) and we try to match our data with the time provided from it (which it takes from GPS satellites).

For setting the actual time from python we utilize a similar solution that is provided here: [Python module to change system date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081310/python-module-to-change-system-date-and-time)

Our issue is that we will always get a permissions error and we are looking for answers here.

Things that are not acceptable:

- Running the software with sudo
- Running the software as root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `CAP_SYS_TIME` capability to your app. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

Comment: Worked like a charm. Only one note: since we are using python and a virtual environment, we had to set the capability for the `/path/to/venv/bin/python`.