# How to change a system date with python on windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to change system date, adding 8 days to current date. But unfortunately I am receiving

```
TypeError: SetSystemTime() takes exactly 8 arguments (1 given)
```

My code is:

```
import datetime
import win32api

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print (now)
tomorrow = now + datetime.timedelta(days = 8)
print (tomorrow)
win32api.SetSystemTime(tomorrow)
```

So I need to turn my 'tomorrow' valuable into a string with 8 arguments. or maybe there is a better function than SetSystemTime. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python module to change system date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081310/python-module-to-change-system-date-and-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to the method [win32api.SetSystemTime](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__SetSystemTime_meth.html) all the arguments must be of type integer.

```
import datetime
import win32api

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print (now)
tomorrow = now + datetime.timedelta(days = 8)
print (tomorrow)

year = int(tomorrow.year)
month = int(tomorrow.month)
# Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.
dayOfWeek = int(tomorrow.weekday())
day = int(tomorrow.day)
hour = int(tomorrow.hour)
minute = int(tomorrow.minute)
second = int(tomorrow.second)
millseconds = int((tomorrow.microsecond)/1000)

win32api.SetSystemTime(year, month , dayOfWeek , day , hour , minute , second , millseconds)
```

[image: output]